# Autoresize UICollectionViewCells for different IPhones devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Some time ago i upgrade xcode and found some changes in storyboard designing. So before, I just create UICollectionView controller with UICollectionViewCell. I set manualy width and height of the cell on it and for all subItems in cell. So, when I run app on different iphones it always have different size, but same spaces between cells. And It also resize cells and content in it. See screenshots for Iphone5S and iphone6[image]

[image]

But now, With the same settings the result are not the same
[image]
[image]

Sa U can see spaces between cells are different in iphone5S and Iphone6. So how can I set regular size for space between cells and make cells bigger for different iphones. My app is only for Iphones with portrait mode

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
CGFloat margin = 10;
int itemsPerRow = 3;

CGFloat itemSideSize = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - itemsPerRow * margin) / 2;
[(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(itemSideSize, itemSizeSize)];
[(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:margin];
[(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:margin];
[(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(margin, margin, margin, margin)];
```